# I need help making prims algorithm the way my instructor wants

Tags: java, prims-algorithm

So i have checked through the previously posted prims algorithm posts. and i cant find one that satisfies my teachers requirements. I worked on this code with him, and have it mostly working. however for somereason when it gets to a certian point, it breaks and goes to the wrong edge.

```
'''public int prims(T startVertex) {
        int tempWeight = 0;
        int championWeight = 0;
        int totalWeight = 0;
        int i = 0;
        boolean firstOne = false;
        T championVertex = null;
        T currentVertex = null;
        T checkVertex = null;
        T championMarked = null;
        UnboundedQueueInterface<T> vertexQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<T>();

        clearMarks();
        markVertex(startVertex);
        currentVertex = startVertex;

        do {
            for (int y = 0; y < numVertices; y++) {
                currentVertex = vertices[y];
                if (isMarked(currentVertex)) {
                    championWeight = 0;
                    championVertex = null;
                    checkVertex = null;
                    firstOne = true;
                    vertexQueue = getToVertices(currentVertex);

                    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        checkVertex = vertexQueue.dequeue();
                        if ((!(isMarked(checkVertex)))) {
                            tempWeight = weightIs(currentVertex, checkVertex);
                            if (championWeight > tempWeight || firstOne == true) {
                                championWeight = tempWeight;
                                championVertex = checkVertex;
                                championMarked = currentVertex;
                                firstOne = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            System.out.println((String) championMarked + (String) championVertex + championWeight);
            markVertex(championVertex);

            totalWeight += championWeight;
        } while (!(getUnmarked() == null));
        System.out.println("Total cost is " + totalWeight);
        return totalWeight; '''
```

when i run it i get the following output
Graph 1
AD1
DF4
FC3
FE12
FZ17
Enull0

the output is correct for the graph until the line FE12. it should be CE4. when i run debug, i watch the code find the answer, but then jumps up to the for loop and looses the right answer. I know there is an error in my logic, but I cant quite figure it out. Your input is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i have figured out my issue, I needed to put the resets for the code, after the code outputs the solution, otherwise where they were, if there were any vertices left to check that were not used already, the code would loose the current values.

they needed to go here

```
'''System.out.println((String) championMarked + (String) championVertex + 
   championWeight);
   markVertex(championVertex);
        totalWeight += championWeight;
        championWeight = 0;
        championVertex = null;
        checkVertex = null;
        firstOne = true;

        } while (!(getUnmarked() == null));'''
```